# There must be a really fast way to calculate this bitwise expression?

Tags: c++, algorithm, assembly, binary, x86

Let v and w be two bitstrings. In the current application they consist of 8 bits. I am looking for the fastest way to calculate the following expression.

```
x = (v[1] & w[0]) ^ (v[2] & w[1]) ^ (v[2] & w[0]) ^ (v[3] & w[2]) ^ (v[3]) & w[1]) ^ (v[3] & w[0]) ^ ...
```

Some ideas on the subject: one thing I noticed is that this expression can also be written as below. Let

```
P(w[k]) = w[k] ^ w[k-1] ^ ... ^ w[0]
```

denote the parity of the lowest `k + 1` bits of w. Then

```
x = (v[1] & P(w[0])) ^ (v[2] & P(w[1])) ^ (v[3] & P(w[2])) ^ ... ^ (v[7] & P(w[6]))
```

Now if `Pw` is a bitstring in which each bit denotes the parity of the lower bits, i.e. for which `Pw[i] = P(w[i-1])` then `x` could be written as follows:

```
x = P(v & Pw)
```

Now, on http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html I found a quick way to calculate the parity of a string, but in order to build a fast algorithm based on this, I would also need a fast way to calculate the bitstring `Pw` described above.

Or maybe I'm going about this in the wrong way completely, there are an awful lot of parity calculations to be done this way. If this is indeed the way to go, I was wondering if it would be possible (assuming the program will run on x86) to use the parity flag in assembly to speed up the calculation.

Finally, this would be a calculation that would be needed a LOT in the application I am developing, so speed is really of the seence. I was wondering if it would be possible to do the entire calculation within a register and if this could be faster than creating a lookup table in memory.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Do `w[i]` and `v[i]` refer to bit positions within 8-bit variables `w` and `v`, or are `w` and `v` arrays of 8-bit variables?  I'm pretty sure, given the first statement in your question, `w[i]` refers to bit `i` of `w`.  Your example above only looks at 7 bits of `w` and 7 bits of `v`.  If that's the case, you can compute a 16384 entry lookup table with the results of the computation and use that at runtime.

Comment: P[w[k]] ? As w is a bitstring, w[k] is either 0 or 1. but if you calculate P[w[k]] for different k, possibility is there will be different values for different k but same w[k].

Comment: user2987424, I downvoted the question because your P[w[k]] notation is all screwed up, as noted a few hours ago, and you haven't fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

If v and w are truly 8 bits, then you could just precalculate all 256^2 combinations and store the result in a table of 65K bytes.  That will easily fit into a cache.  Your computation then becomes:

```
  precomputed[v<<8+w]
```

which is a few machine clocks and a hot cache line lookup.  Might be hard to beat.

Answer (score 3):

On x86 the parity bit is automatically calculated for low 8-bit arithmetic operations. Basically the required operations are reduced to:

```
 Pw = Lookup_256[w];
 v &= Pw;                 // get the Parity as side effect on x86, or

 v  = Lookup_256[v] >> 7; // Reuse the table to get parity for bit 7
```

**EDIT**

Higher level optimizations and parallel implementation is achievable by recognizing that the partial products (v[i] & w[j]) are internal part of multiplication and that the concatenation with the operator `^` makes this overall operation carry-less (or polynomial).

The overall operation would be Parity( ((v >> 1) Px w) & 0xff), where Px denotes polynomial multiplication, which is supported in e.g. NEON and in intel architecture with PCLMULQDQ instruction. The Intel instruction (unfortunately) operates in 64-bit words, making it probably possible, but difficult to incorporate several independent vectors v,w to be multiplied simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
register int v, w, parity=0;
/* ... */
v >>= 1; /* Discard lsb? */
while (v) {
  parity ^= v ^ w;
  w = (w & 1) ^ (w >> 1);
  v >>= 1;
}
parity &= 1;
```